# Powershell remoting to a server using CNAME, not COMPUTER NAME

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I am trying to get powershell remoting to work with a server using it's CNAME rather than the computer name. Both local and remote machines are on the same network and domain.

I have enabled powershell remoting, and it works fine with the computer name. I have set my TrustedHosts to the CNAME and have added the SPN for the CNAME, however when I issue the `Enter-PSSession CNAME` I get the following:

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server CNAME failed with the following
error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error
occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer CNAME.
Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name
provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Executing `setspn -l COMPUTERNAME` gives me this:

```
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=COMPUTERNAME,OU=SERVERS,DC=COMPANY,DC=private:
        WSMAN/CNAME
        WSMAN/COMPUTERNAME
        WSMAN/COMPUTERNAME.local
        TERMSRV/COMPUTERNAME
        TERMSRV/COMPUTERNAME.local
        HOST/COMPUTERNAME
        HOST/COMPUTERNAME.local
```

What else is needed to enable access via the CNAME?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did to resolve this issue was to create a proxy function for Enter-PSSession that resolves the CNAME for me. This might not work in your case, depending on *why* you need to use the CNAME, but this works for me.

Details on proxy powershell functions: http://www.windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-with-a-purpose-blog-36/windows-powershell/powershell-proxy-functions-141413

Full function:

```
function Enter-PSSession {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='ComputerName')]
param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerName', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('Cn')]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    ${ComputerName},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Session', Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession]
${Session},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Uri', Position=1, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[Alias('URI','CU')]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[uri]
${ConnectionUri},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='InstanceId', ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateNotNull()]
[guid]
${InstanceId},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Id', Position=0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateNotNull()]
[int]
${Id},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Name', ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
${Name},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Uri')]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerName')]
[switch]
${EnableNetworkAccess},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerName', ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Uri', ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[system.management.automation.pscredential]
${Credential},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerName')]
[ValidateRange(1, 65535)]
[int]
${Port},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerName')]
[switch]
${UseSSL},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerName', ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Uri', ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
${ConfigurationName},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerName', ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[string]
${ApplicationName},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Uri')]
[switch]
${AllowRedirection},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Uri')]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerName')]
[ValidateNotNull()]
[System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSSessionOption]
${SessionOption},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Uri')]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerName')]
[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AuthenticationMechanism]
${Authentication},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Uri')]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerName')]
[string]
${CertificateThumbprint})


begin
{
    try {
        $outBuffer = $null
        if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
        {
            $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
        }
        $PSBoundParameters['ComputerName'] = ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($PSBoundParameters['ComputerName'])).HostName
        $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Enter-PSSession', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
        $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
        $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

process
{
    try {
        $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

end
{
    try {
        $steppablePipeline.End()
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}
<#

.ForwardHelpTargetName Enter-PSSession
.ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet

#>

}
```

The only line I added was:

```
$PSBoundParameters['ComputerName'] = ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($PSBoundParameters['ComputerName'])).HostName
```

This simply resolves the CNAME to the FQDN in the proxy function before calling the native Enter-PSSession.

This allows me to set *.mydomain.local in my TrustedHosts via Group Policy, and I can still use "Enter-PSSession ShortName" or "Enter-PSSession CNAME" without having to mess with additional SPNs, etc.

Comment: Works nice. Thx.